# jQuery, HTML, PHP email form $.post()

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('Type').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('Message').value;
    $.post("send.php", {
        Name: "Matt",
        Email: "xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
        Type: "1",
        Message: "GO"
    },

    function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

But this code does not:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
        var type = document.getElementById('Type').value;
        var message = document.getElementById('Message').value;
        $.post("send.php", {
            Name: "Matt",
            Email: "xxxxxx.wsu@hotmail.com",
            Type: "1",
            Message: "GO"
        },

        function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, I have checked my `#btn` and the id is correct so its not that. The first code returns successful and the email send. The second one does nothing and I cannot debug it well because the response from the server does not show up in my Chrome Developer Tools Network viewer.

Here is the html form:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
                <label for="Name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">

                <label for="Email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email">

                <label for="Type">Type: </label>
                <select name="Type" id="Type">
                    <option value="0">General</option>
                    <option value="1">I need a consultation</option>
                    <option value="2">I need a website</option>
                </select>

                <label for="Message">Message: </label>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="Message" id="Message"></textarea>
                <br />
                <button id="btn" class="submitBtn">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post your `html` as well? If not all, at least the relevant part. Also can you check what `firebug` has to say?

Comment: Are you sure your event handler for `#btn` is working? Try adding an `alert()` at the start to see if it fires onclick.

Comment: Which email you want to send either  "mhintzke.wsu@hotmail.com" or "xxxxxx@hotmail.com". "#btn" is working see in this link http://jsfiddle.net/Ssp2v/

Comment: the mhintzke was a typo, i was just hiding it but forgot the second copy and paste...i can't find any typos, ill check firefox

Comment: and i have been debugging with alert()'s all day..it fires in the click() handler..no idea whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `type` for the `<button>` as **button**.

```
<button type="button" id="btn" class="submitBtn" >Send</button>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kXeY8/

Some browsers interpret the default `type` for a `<button>` in a form with no `type` attribute specified as **submit**, causing your form to submit instead, preventing the `click` event's ajax request from finishing.

Comment: WOW! thank you so much..Why did this work but the others not? even though the event still fired because the alert() went off... Please explain

Comment: Edited to provide some context.